# assigning column vector to multiple data.frame object as common attributes

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I have three data.frame object, also there is vector that must be added as new attributes to them. I know it is easy to add attribute to data.frame objects, but I want to assign common vector all object together. Is there any better way to do this? How can I make it more efficient to achieve this?

```
# simulated data
df1 <- CO2[1:10,]
df2 <- airquality[1:10,]
df3 <- iris[1:10,]

# objective: assign vector avg.score to df1, df2, df3 together
# this is my attempt:
avg.score <- c(2.95,38.96,5.08,35.84,3.86,4.08,3.97,4.33,3.23,4.08)
df1$avg.score <- avg.score
df2$avg.score <- avg.score
df3$avg.score <- avg.score
```

I think my attempt solution is not good enough, I bet there must be more easy way to do this. Can anyone give me some ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try,

```
l1 <- list(df1, df2, df3)
lapply(l1, function(i) cbind(i, avg.score))
```